Is there a way to delete a complete command (from previous semicolon or bracket to and including next semicolon) in Visual Studio Code?
Lets say I have a code snippet:
if (unbelivable){
    std::cerr << "some very long"
              << "multiline"
              << "error message" 
              << std::endl;

    std::raise(SIGTERM);
}

I am trying to delete the 4 lines long print statement. Currently I have to either select the 4 lines to delete them at once. Or to execute delete multiple times one for each line. Is there a shortcut that would allow me to delete the complete print statent at once? Everything between the opening bracket and (and including) the closing semicolon? Similar, is there a way to delete a complete code block of the if with a hotkey?

"Expand Selection" (editor.action.smartSelect.expand) does part of what you want. I don't know C++ myself, but I tried it on a rough equivalent in Python and it was able to select the print function call but not the if-statement, but then Python doesn't use brackets for that.
